# Letsencrypt DST Root CA X3 Problem with Magento SOAP-Service client or server side?

Tags: magento, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Since 30.9. - due to DST Root CA X3 SOAP Calls (SOAPUI or PHP SoapCLient) against the system fail. However via webbrowser I can open the https-Website just fine.

```
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = xyz.de
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=xyz.de
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
   i:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
 2 s:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=xyz.de
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4657 bytes and written 292 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: E6AC1CB5A43712F0CDB1FA843B35D31F16195096541920D4A7C5F60E5089797C
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: B621EBF40CB97A41A1DFAEBAD317FA48F01723BE72A25D6BBD6CCA7F91C4968399BCA3E146E20F2D44160F09BC1572E1
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 600 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - a3 a3 ce f3 2a c0 9e f7-60 59 91 f6 15 c9 56 79   ....*...`Y....Vy
    0010 - 31 f8 d7 d0 cb a4 1b de-7d 1d bf 12 73 4e 5a f1   1.......}...sNZ.
    0020 - b9 12 8b ff 1c c1 28 f7-cb d3 d1 f3 0e 4c 75 64   ......(......Lud
    0030 - ce 3d c5 28 4e 99 5b e4-37 d4 b4 1b 4e 91 b8 e3   .=.(N.[.7...N...
    0040 - 08 68 8f 6b 8a 1e dd f1-a3 79 f1 f6 1d 81 5f e7   .h.k.....y...._.
    0050 - 7f 34 78 0a 48 ab 34 aa-f1 41 e1 5b 5c 89 75 b7   .4x.H.4..A.[\.u.
    0060 - d2 54 a9 8b 63 ee 66 f3-e7 ee aa df 6b 61 ee 9b   .T..c.f.....ka..
    0070 - d1 89 28 c6 f1 96 53 d3-29 d0 7f d3 28 5b 52 b1   ..(...S.)...([R.
    0080 - 0c fb 37 10 1d 23 a4 d1-6e 4a ff 39 f5 9c f7 a6   ..7..#..nJ.9....
    0090 - ad 05 e3 a3 bb 98 04 f3-9d 23 6c ea 10 3f a2 22   .........#l..?."
    00a0 - 39 76 0b 16 5b f6 af 0d-1a 2d 10 56 6e 72 d0 f1   9v..[....-.Vnr..

    Start Time: 1633688139
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

The certificate chain still uses DST Root CA X3 but I dont know if this is ok or not:

```
 2 s:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
```

Error-Message from all Soap-Clients i tried is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://xyz.de/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://xyz.de/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1"
```

Is the problem on server side, or more like an issue that ISRG Root X1 is not known on client side?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the problem is, that the System (Magento Version 1) is calling itself via Web to get the WSDL, and the System that is hosting Magento was using the outdated DST ROOT CA X3 plus did not know about the ISRG Root X1:

```
rm /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
apt-get install ca-certificates -y
update-ca-certificates -f -v
```

Comment: What PHP version are you on ? I am having the same issue but your solution didn't help.

Comment: the question is more about  what distribution are you using. It is totally not about the PHP version!